# Where can i see the custom buttons set on search layouts in Lightning Desktop?

Tags: lightning-experience, winter16

We have added some buttons on the leads search layout which is visible on the classic salesforce layout but when i enable Lightning Desktop. These buttons are not visible on list view. Any idea if we can make them available to display

[image]

Comment: I had a few issues within things not being visible on the lightning view list, like the view list configuration gear to edit the view lists. When I asked Salesforce about it, they said that not everything was available right now. I do not know if that includes custom buttons or not.

Comment: **Search Layouts disappear if Allow Search is unchecked on any custom object.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the buttons you are missing are Javascript or URL buttons, they are not supported in Lightning Experience.

Source: [Trailhead Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_rightforme#Tdxn4tBK-heading13)

Answer (score 2):

url buttons are supported in LIGHTNING for search layouts, js buttons are not :(

"Display Checkboxes (for Multi-Record Selection) option after selecting List Button" likely not supported as well.

Is it possible to use standardSetController for the search layout (Contacts tab) lightning or the only way it is create custom page with multi select?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've noticed is that buttons on Recently Viewed are different (default) from All records or custom list views.

So if you are wondering why your newly added button doesn't appear on a list view, just change the list view!